# Google Or-tools disjunction of constraints

Tags: java, constraint-satisfaction, or-tools

I would like to use the **Google or-tools Java** api and I can't make disjunction of constraints. I try to implement like this: (A==1 OR B==1) AND ((C==1 OR D==1))... How can I do that?

And the other question is how can I implement the makeSumLessOrEqual(IntVar[] VARS, IntVar limit) because there is only makeSumLessOrEqual(IntVar[] VARS, int limit) function.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to use the Google or-tools Java api and I can't make disjunction of constraints. I try to implement like this: (A==1 OR B==1) AND ((C==1 OR D==1))... How can I do that?

Create boolean variables with `solver.makeIsEqualCstVar(A, 1)`

The `OR` is `solver.makeMax(boolvar_1, boolvar_2)` and 
`AND` is `solver.makeMin();`

> And the other question is how can I implement the makeSumLessOrEqual(IntVar[] VARS, IntVar limit) because there is only makeSumLessOrEqual(IntVar[] VARS, int limit) function.

You need to use the `makeScalProd` API with `[1, .., 1, -1]` and `vars + [limit]`.

Comment: Still, I would recommend using the CP-SAT solver. You can have a look at: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md, https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md, and https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/ .